# How do I access the assembly version and name from inside the assembly/WCF service?

Tags: c#, wcf

I would like to provide an operation contract in my WCF library that returns select information, i.e. version, assembly name, some other internal values.

The purpose is to provide a "Service Check" method for diagnostics and such that can be called as a regular WCF.

I am having trouble figuring out the best way to do this. I imagine some sort of internal reflection.

I would also like to put this code inside the Interface as part of the operation contract.

What is the best way to do this?

Comment: How about calling **Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().FullName**?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can do this using reflection:

For example, to get the assembly's version info:

```
return System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetName().Version
```